# how to extend ImageView class in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, imageview

I found strange behavior when extending `ImageView` in kotlin.
I have following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <AlphaImage
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blitz_1st_place" />
</FrameLayout>
```

`AlphaImage` class:

```
class AlphaImage(context: Context,attrs:AttributeSet?=null):ImageView(context,attrs) {
}
```

The layout preview in android studio shows image as 100% transparent as well as in runtime.There are no errors in the layout editor.What interesting is if I change `AlphaImage` to `ImageView` image starts to display its content as expected.Why is this happening?How do I extend `ImageView`?

Comment: That layout should be throwing an Exception during inflation. Do you actually have the fully-qualified class name for `AlphaImage` in its layout tag in the code you're actually running?

Comment: OK, then the issue is the `app:srcCompat` attribute. That is a support/androidx library attribute for the `AppCompatImageView` class, and the framework `ImageView` will just ignore it. The reason it works when you change the tag to `<ImageView>` is because the support/androidx library `LayoutInflater` will automatically substitute `AppCompatImageView` for any `<ImageView>` tag it finds, and the `AppCompatImageView` will find the `app:srcCompat`attribute, and handle its value appropriately. If you want your class to handle that attribute automatically, extend `AppCompatImageView` instead.

Comment: yes I do have  fully-qualified class names

Comment: Yep, I anticipated that, and already had my next comment ready above. :-)

Comment: Indeed!Could you format your comment as an answer?Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the `app:srcCompat` attribute. That is a support/androidx library attribute for the `AppCompatImageView` class. The framework `ImageView` will just ignore it.

The reason this works when you use an `<ImageView>` tag instead is because the support/androidx `LayoutInflater` that `AppCompatActivity` uses will automatically substitute an `AppCompatImageView` for any `<ImageView>` tag it finds. The `AppCompatImageView` will then see that `app:srcCompat` attribute, and handle its value appropriately.

If you'd like your custom class to handle that attribute automatically, simply extend `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView`.